# Input file format for email classification with svm-light

Tags: python, input, text-processing, svmlight

I am working with email subject, so I have 20 emails i want to classify, and a file with 20 lines - one line has one email subject.I have been working on it, but I am unable to figure out what the features refer to and the format of the input file for svmlight. Any tips to proceed will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

I have taken the tf-idf of the first 500 subject lines as a trial. However, according to svm-light format, we need:

```
<line> .=. <target> <feature>:<value> <feature>:<value> ... <feature>:<value> # <info>
```

I have only the tf-idf features for 500 lines. Sadly, this is not read by the svm-light as it needs features/value pair. Any ideas on what the value could be or how I can change the file in order to be read?

An idea of the file I have(first 5 email features):

```
1 201 1.0
2 280 0.123165672613
2 313 0.343915400191
2 515 0.157569797284
2 588 0.343915400191
2 652 0.343915400191
2 657 0.343915400191
2 774 0.23622904941
2 921 0.283118375032
2 1158 0.254849368195
2 1240 0.343915400191
2 1348 0.343915400191
2 1362 0.222321349873
3 57 0.342220321154
3 185 0.391349077827
3 244 0.391349077827
3 300 0.391349077827
3 693 0.391349077827
3 730 0.342220321154
3 1391 0.391349077827
4 57 0.342220321154
4 185 0.391349077827
4 244 0.391349077827
4 300 0.391349077827
4 693 0.391349077827
4 730 0.342220321154
4 1391 0.391349077827
5 32 0.323558487577
5 102 0.323558487577
5 157 0.364177022553
5 160 0.364177022553
5 718 0.151013895297
5 1171 0.364177022553
5 1277 0.323558487577
5 1308 0.364177022553
5 1336 0.364177022553
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated, as I have been stuck at this point for quite long now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python file format for email classification with svm-light](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807724/python-file-format-for-email-classification-with-svm-light)

Comment: Did you try the obvious serialization `1 201:1.0` and `2 280:0.123165672613 313:0343915400191 515:0.15759797284`...?  How did it fail?